# Calling an applet in another applet with buttons?

Tags: java, applet

I want the contents of one applet to be displayed when a button is pressed in another applet. The applet I'm calling is a game. I'm doing this for school and I can't use JApplet for this or use a webpage. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Inter-applets communication are possible but as i remember the condition is to be on the same webpage. This is the simplest solution. Eg: https://www.javatpoint.com/Applet-Communication. With out a web page the solution could be a little more elaborate, something like to set up a communication based client-server model (tcp/upd). One applet will send the message and other on receive will do something. Further more as i know modern browsers do not support applets, and if need to use a browser you will need something till 2016.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check with my teacher then.